# java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster

Tags: java, изображения, bufferedimage

Я хочу обрезать изображение и получить квадратное изображение. Пример:

Исходное изображение: 1000x667

Хочу получить: 667х667

Из такого изображения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Получить такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы изображение обрезалось по центру

Мой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/someone/test/1.jpeg"));
        int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : image.getType();
        int x = 0,y=0,w=0,h=0;

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int delta = (width - height)/2;

        if (delta != 0){
            if(delta > 0){
                x = delta;
                y = height;
                w = height;
                h = height;
            }
            if(delta < 0){
                x = 0;
                y = height + delta;
                w = width;
                h = width;
            }
            image = image.getSubimage(x,y,w,h);
            ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",new File( "/home/someone/test/1a.jpeg"));
        }

    } catch (RasterFormatException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster

Знаю что ошибка возникает в этой строке

```
image = image.getSubimage(x,y,w,h);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя ошибка была в том что за начальной точкой координат (x=0 u y=0)  брал левую-нижнюю угол. А надо было левую-верхнюю взять

Исправленный код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/rahimov/test/4.jpeg"));
        int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : image.getType();
        int x = 0, y=166,w=667,h=667;

       BufferedImage image2 = image.getSubimage(x,y,w,h);
        ImageIO.write(image2,"jpg",new File( "/home/rahimov/test/4b.jpeg"));
    } catch (RasterFormatException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```